# cmake analogues to qmake string literals

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qmake

there is a .pri as a part of qmake project which contains some global string definitions :

```
STR1 = string literal 1
STR2 = string literal 2
GIT_VERSION = $$system($$ENV_GIT_EXE_PATH describe --long)
```

and these strings used in a code :

```
QString str1 = QStringLiteral(STR1);
QString str2 = QStringLiteral(STR2);
QString str3 = QStringLiteral(GIT_VERSION);
```

How to implement this functionality using cmake project? I can't change the sources (C++.h/.cpp) and have to  prepare those strings somehow using cmake abilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qmake’s string literals are nothing but a preprocessor macro definitions.
In CMake this can be done with [`add_compile_definitions`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/add_compile_definitions.html#command:add_compile_definitions) or with [`target_compile_definitions`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/target_compile_definitions.html)

So the analogue would be:

```
add_compile_definitions(STR1="string literal 1")
add_compile_definitions(STR2="string literal 2")
execute_process(COMMAND ${ENV_GIT_EXE_PATH} describe --long
OUTPUT_VARIABLE git_version)
add_compile_definitions(GIT_VERSION="${git_version}")
```

PS. You can access environment variables with `$ENV{GIT_EXE_PATH}`

Comment: what is a difference between add_compile_definitions and  add_definitions ?

Comment: @amigo421 add_definitions is an old version of the mentioned commands and as far as I know it is there only for backwards compatibility